# Finding the remaining time from one list that isn't in another

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I have been banging my head against a brick wall for a while with this one! 
I am close but I can't quite get the desired result and was hoping someone might be able to tell me where I am going wrong.

I have 2 lists of objects which contain a start and end time.

### List A

```
12/03/2019 04:13:50 - 12/03/2019 06:28:52
12/03/2019 06:31:06 - 12/03/2019 06:32:09
12/03/2019 06:33:11 - 12/03/2019 06:34:48
12/03/2019 06:35:26 - 12/03/2019 06:39:52
12/03/2019 06:42:33 - 12/03/2019 08:19:31
12/03/2019 08:30:03 - 12/03/2019 08:31:07
12/03/2019 08:36:56 - 12/03/2019 09:16:31
12/03/2019 09:17:17 - 12/03/2019 10:00:00
```

### List B

```
12/03/2019 06:25:35 - 12/03/2019 06:28:52
12/03/2019 06:45:23 - 12/03/2019 06:52:29
12/03/2019 06:57:43 - 12/03/2019 06:58:05
12/03/2019 06:59:46 - 12/03/2019 07:07:58
12/03/2019 07:11:09 - 12/03/2019 07:21:36
12/03/2019 07:33:10 - 12/03/2019 07:38:13
12/03/2019 07:39:54 - 12/03/2019 07:43:27
12/03/2019 07:44:01 - 12/03/2019 07:45:41
12/03/2019 07:49:59 - 12/03/2019 08:02:13
12/03/2019 08:03:31 - 12/03/2019 08:12:51
12/03/2019 08:17:09 - 12/03/2019 08:19:31
12/03/2019 08:42:04 - 12/03/2019 08:47:13
12/03/2019 09:51:37 - 12/03/2019 10:00:00
```

I would like to produce a new list of start and end time objects from list a that are not in list B.

### Desired Result

```
12/03/2019 04:13:50 - 12/03/2019 06:25:35
12/03/2019 06:31:06 - 12/03/2019 06:32:09
12/03/2019 06:33:11 - 12/03/2019 06:34:48
12/03/2019 06:35:26 - 12/03/2019 06:39:52
12/03/2019 06:42:33 - 12/03/2019 06:45:23
12/03/2019 06:52:29 - 12/03/2019 06:57:43
12/03/2019 06:58:05 - 12/03/2019 06:59:46
12/03/2019 07:07:58 - 12/03/2019 07:11:09
12/03/2019 07:21:36 - 12/03/2019 07:33:10
12/03/2019 07:38:13 - 12/03/2019 07:39:54
12/03/2019 07:43:27 - 12/03/2019 07:44:01
12/03/2019 07:45:41 - 12/03/2019 07:49:59
12/03/2019 08:02:13 - 12/03/2019 08:03:31
12/03/2019 08:12:51 - 12/03/2019 08:17:09
12/03/2019 08:30:03 - 12/03/2019 08:31:07
12/03/2019 08:36:56 - 12/03/2019 08:42:04
12/03/2019 08:47:13 - 12/03/2019 09:16:31
12/03/2019 09:17:17 - 12/03/2019 09:51:37
```

Here is the method I am using at the moment that is getting me the closest.

```
    public ShiftPattern GetRemainingTimesWithinShiftPattern(List<State> listB)
    {
        var shifts = new ShiftPattern();
        for (var a = 0; a < listB.Count; a++)
        {
            foreach (var shift in this) // this = listA
            {
                if (shift.IsTimeWithinShift(listB[a].StateStart) || shift.IsTimeWithinShift(listB[a].StateEnd))
                {
                    if (shift.IsTimeWithinShift(listB[a].StateStart))
                    {
                        var inoutShift = new Shift
                        {
                            StartDay = shift.StartDay,
                            StartTime = shift.StartTime,
                            EndDay = listB[a].StateStart.Date,
                            EndTime = listB[a].StartMsSinceMidnight
                        };
                        shifts.Add(inoutShift);
                    }
                    if (shift.IsTimeWithinShift(listB[a].StateEnd))
                    {
                        for (var c = a + 1; c < listB.Count; c++)
                        {
                            var inoutShift = new Shift();
                            inoutShift.StartDay = listB[a].StateEnd.Date;
                            inoutShift.StartTime = listB[a].EndMsSinceMidnight;
                            if (shift.IsTimeWithinShift(listB[c].StateStart))
                            {
                                inoutShift.EndDay = listB[c].StateStart.Date;
                                inoutShift.EndTime = listB[c].StartMsSinceMidnight;
                                shifts.Add(inoutShift);
                            }
                            else if (shift.EndTime > listB[a].EndMsSinceMidnight) // this is so we don't get a start and stop for the same time.
                            {
                                inoutShift.EndDay = shift.EndDay;
                                inoutShift.EndTime = shift.EndTime;
                                shifts.Add(inoutShift);
                                break;
                            }
                            a++;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return shifts;
    }
```

The results I am getting are

```
12/03/2019 04:13:50 - 12/03/2019 06:25:35
12/03/2019 06:42:33 - 12/03/2019 06:45:23
12/03/2019 06:52:29 - 12/03/2019 06:57:43
12/03/2019 06:58:05 - 12/03/2019 06:59:46
12/03/2019 07:07:58 - 12/03/2019 07:11:09
12/03/2019 07:21:36 - 12/03/2019 07:33:10
12/03/2019 07:38:13 - 12/03/2019 07:39:54
12/03/2019 07:43:27 - 12/03/2019 07:44:01
12/03/2019 07:45:41 - 12/03/2019 07:49:59
12/03/2019 08:02:13 - 12/03/2019 08:03:31
12/03/2019 08:12:51 - 12/03/2019 08:17:09
12/03/2019 09:17:17 - 12/03/2019 09:51:37
```

**EDIT**

Here are a couple of sample classes that produce lists A & B

```
    public class StartStop
    {
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime Stop { get; set; }
    }
    public List<StartStop> GetListA()
    {
        return new List<StartStop>
        {
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(4).AddMinutes(13).AddSeconds(50), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(28).AddSeconds(52) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(31).AddSeconds(6), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(32).AddSeconds(9) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(33).AddSeconds(11), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(34).AddSeconds(48) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(35).AddSeconds(26), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(39).AddSeconds(52) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(42).AddSeconds(33), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(19).AddSeconds(31) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(30).AddSeconds(3), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(31).AddSeconds(7) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(36).AddSeconds(56), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(16).AddSeconds(31) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(17).AddSeconds(17), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10) }
        };
    }
    public List<StartStop> GetListB()
    {
        return new List<StartStop>
        {
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(25).AddSeconds(35), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(28).AddSeconds(52) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(45).AddSeconds(23), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(52).AddSeconds(29) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(57).AddSeconds(43), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(58).AddSeconds(5) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(46), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(7).AddSeconds(58) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(11).AddSeconds(9), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(21).AddSeconds(36) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(33).AddSeconds(10), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(38).AddSeconds(13) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(39).AddSeconds(54), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(43).AddSeconds(27) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(44).AddSeconds(1), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(45).AddSeconds(41) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(49).AddSeconds(59), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(2).AddSeconds(13) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(3).AddSeconds(31), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(12).AddSeconds(51) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(17).AddSeconds(9), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(19).AddSeconds(31) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(42).AddSeconds(4), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(47).AddSeconds(13) },
            new StartStop { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(51).AddSeconds(37), Stop  = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10) },
        };
    }
```

Comment: How do you want the overlaps to be handled?  The start/end times in list B can overlap list A and not sure what you actually need.  I'm also not sure how you came up with the desired results.

Comment: It would help if you could provide the sample data using a small dummy class with start and end dates and some C# code to populate it. It's a lot of work to take your presented samples and get to some runnable code with it so it saves a lot of time and effort if you do that once rather than forcing any would-be answerers to all have to do that work.

Comment: I think Jon Skeet made a mistake when formatting the desired result, as it has these two pairs of objects `12/03/2019 06:42:33 - 12/03/2019 06:45:23` and `12/03/2019 06:52:29 - 12/03/2019 06:57:43` but as far as I understand it should be `12/03/2019 06:45:23 - 12/03/2019 06:52:29` as this actually occurs in the listB the [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55123421/1) of this question show this as well

Comment: @MindSwipe - take the two lists together. Find all periods of time where at least one item in list A overlaps that period, and no item in list B does. These are the new periods that appear in the output. So you get `6:42 - 6:45` because a period started in list A at 6:42, but at 6:45 a new period started in list B so that's why it ends.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm creating a sample class now.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code sample contains some oddities, such as periods that Stop before they Start. Do you have to cope with such items?

Comment: @Damien, no I have already processed the lists before this stage so that shouldn’t happen. I just cocked up the sample data because I was in a rush. I will correct it when back at a pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd break it down something like this, using LINQ. Untested since I don't need the typing practice from your sample data<sup>1</sup>:

```
  var listA = new List<Something>();
  var listB = new List<Something>();
  var result = new List<Something>();

  var allPeriods = listA
    .SelectMany(st => new[] {
      new { AtTime = st.StartTime, A = 1, B = 0 },
      new { AtTime = st.EndTime, A = -1, B = 0} })
    .Concat(listB.SelectMany(st => new[]
    {
      new {AtTime = st.StartTime, A = 0, B = 1},
      new {AtTime = st.EndTime, A = 0, B = -1}
    }));
  var sorted = allPeriods.OrderBy(per => per.AtTime).ToList();
  var paired = sorted.Zip(sorted.Skip(1),
       (first, second) => new { Start = first, End = second });
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  foreach(var pair in paired)
  {
    a += pair.Start.A;
    b += pair.Start.B;
    if (a > 0 && b == 0)
    {
      result.Add(new Something {
        StartTime = pair.Start.AtTime,
        EndTime = pair.End.AtTime });
    }
  }
```

Hopefully you can see the logic I'm using here. I basically extract all of the possible start and end times, and pair them up in order. I then process through them and keep a running count of how many A's and B's are now open. If there are As open but no Bs, we output a result.

This won't merge adjoining periods but those shouldn't occur based on your sample data anyway.

Unfortunately this approach does need to take a couple of passes through the data. Unless this is a performance hotspot and you're dealing with lists containing *lots* of items though, I wouldn't worry about it.

The only efficient approaches to this that won't make multiple passes though at least one of the lists requires some kind of multi-dimensional range access based on both start and end dates and I can't think of anything standard in the framework that would work for this.

---

To some extent, this is based on how I'd solve the same problem in SQL, which can more naturally orient itself to this sort of set-based approach. Others may prefer more declarative approaches.

---

<sup>1</sup>If I take your sample data code and make corrections to prevent time travel, this now produces 18 results, which on spot checking match your expected results.

Comment: That is very clever, I would never have thought about doing it that way. It took me a little while to work out how it was working but it does give exactly the correct results and for that I thank you.